# Threadsafe function timeouts in Perl?

Tags: perl, thread-safety, timeout

I have found multiple posts in Stack Overflow about implementing timeouts in Perl. However, I have not seen any information on whether any of the suggested methods are threadsafe.

I have a custom Perl application with multiple threads that each run a particular function. I would like to create a timeout such that if the function running within each thread does not complete within a certain amount of time, execution of that function stops in that particular thread and I run some cleanup code.

A potential workaround could be to run these multiple threads as separate Perl script instances instead to avoid using threads completely, but that would require some major rewriting of my code.

What would be the best way to implement this timeout functionality in a threadsafe manner?

Answer (score 1):

You could use alarms to set a timeout. Read about them [perlpic](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) manual and [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html).

As long you set the signal/alarm inside the thread, you should be fine.